# Count unique values in the HTML TABLE

Tags: javascript, html

I have this HTML table and a script which counts the table-rows with the ID "total__registros". The result is: "Registros: 7"

How can I make the script count unique values only, based on the "NOMBRE" field, that should say, the result is: "Registros: 5"?

I have this SQL statement that does not work in JS:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT NOMBRE) FROM usuarios
```

```js
function totalregistros() {
  var TotalRegistros = document.getElementById("table").rows.length;

  document.getElementById("total__registros").value = "Registros: " + (TotalRegistros - 1);
}

window.onload = totalregistros();
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Nº</td>
      <td>NOMBRE</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Andrea</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Gabriela</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Gabriela</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Alba</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>Jose</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>Luis</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>Alba</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT NOMBRE) FROM usuarios` sounds more like SQL than PHP to me...

Comment: Yes ... but its a example, my project need JAVASCRIPT.

Comment: PS: `JavaScript` nor `script` are acronyms. The only real acronym you used is HTML (Hyper Text Markup Language). Writing it all in capitals does not make it more readable.

Comment: @tacoshy, HTML isn't an acronym either (unless you pronounce it _hitmell_, maybe). It's an initialism or just an abbreviation.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) from all the names, then take its [`size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/size).

```js
const uniqueNames = new Set(Array.from(
  document.querySelectorAll('#table > tbody > tr'), 
  tr => tr.cells[1].textContent
));
console.log(...uniqueNames);
console.log(uniqueNames.size);
```

```html
<table id="table"><thead><tr><td>Nº</td><td>NOMBRE</td></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>1</td><td>Andrea</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>Gabriela</td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>Gabriela</td></tr><tr><td>4</td><td>Alba</td></tr><tr><td>5</td><td>Jose</td></tr><tr><td>6</td><td>Luis</td></tr><tr><td>7</td><td>Alba</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your anwer. I have other HTML table with empty cells and this code count the empty cells too, how make for not count them. I tried modify it so: console.log(uniqueNames.size - 1)  its right?

Comment: @LuisJose You can check for blank text while looping over the rows: `const uniqueNames = new Set; for (const el of document.querySelectorAll('#table > tbody > tr')) { const name = el.cells[1].textContent.trim(); if (name) uniqueNames.add(name); } console.log(uniqueNames.size);`

Comment: Really i learn much in this page, Thank you to all for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

1. use `querySelectorAll` to select all second `td`'s in a `tr`
   of the `tbody`.
2. create an empty array
3. check every Name of step 1 if it is already contained within the array. If not, push the name to the array.
4. Use `array.prototype.length` to count the numbers of unique names:

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const TABLE = document.querySelector('#table');
  const TD_NAMES = document.querySelectorAll('#table tbody tr td:nth-child(2)');
  
  let uniqueNames = [];
  
  TD_NAMES.forEach(NAME => {
    let name = NAME.textContent;
    if (!uniqueNames.includes(name) && name.trim()) {
      uniqueNames.push(name);
    }
  })
  
  console.log(uniqueNames);
  console.log(uniqueNames.length);
})
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Nº</td>
      <td>NOMBRE</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Andrea</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Gabriela</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Gabriela</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Alba</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>Jose</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>Luis</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>Alba</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>8</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

EDIT:

> I have other HTML table with empty cells and this code count the empty cells too, how make for not count them.

Just add `&& name.trim()` to the if-statement. It checks if a cell is empty.

Comment: better to use a `Set` becuase those will automatically filter out unique values

Comment: Thank you for your anwer. I have other HTML table with empty cells and this code count the empty cells too, how make for not count them. I tried modify it so: console.log(uniqueNames.size - 1).

Comment: @LuisJose I added a check condition to check for that too

Answer (score 0):

First, To get values easily, you need to change from td tags inside thead tag to th tag.

Then, collect td tags using DOM.

After that, using map method, get only values and optimize it.

Finally, you can get length of it

```html
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Nº</td>
      <th>NOMBRE</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Andrea</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Gabriela</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Gabriela</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Alba</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>Jose</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>Luis</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>Alba</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

```js
var length = [...new Set(Object.values(document.querySelectorAll("#table td:nth-child(2)")).map(td => td.innerHTML))].length;

console.log(length);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getTableData() {
  var col = [];
  var tbl = document.getElementById('table');//get table
  var rows = tbl.querySelectorAll("tr");//find rows in table
  for(var i = 0;i < rows.length; i++) {
    col.push(rows[i].cells[1].textContent);//get column two values
  }

  console.log(JSON.stringify([...new Set(col)].length));//make unique and get length
}
```

can also be written as:

```
function getTableData() {
      console.log([...new Set(Object.values(document.getElementById('table').querySelectorAll("tr")).map(r => r.cells[1].textContent))].length);
    }
```

The Object.values is a simple way of turning an object into an array for the map method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over the rows and collect the values from the desired column. Then, you use js data structure like an object or a Set to keep track of the unique values.

```js
function totalregistros() {
 var table = document.getElementById("table");
 var rows = table.rows;
 var uniqueNames = {}; // This object will hold the unique names
 var uniqueNameCount = 0; // This variable will hold the count of unique names

 // Iterate over the rows starting from the second one (index 1), skipping the header row
 for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var nameCell = rows[i].cells[1]; // Assuming "NOMBRE" is the second column
    var name = nameCell.innerText; // Get the text content of the cell

    // If the name is not yet in the uniqueNames object, add it and increment the count
    if (name && !uniqueNames[name]) {
      uniqueNames[name] = true;
      uniqueNameCount++;
    }
 }

 document.getElementById("total__registros").value = "Registros: " + uniqueNameCount;
}

window.onload = totalregistros;
```

```html
<table id="table">
 <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Nº</td>
      <td>NOMBRE</td>
    </tr>
 </thead>
  
 <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Andrea</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Gabriela</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Gabriela</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Alba</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>Jose</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>Luis</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>Alba</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
<input type="text" id="total__registros">
```

The code used a condition `if (name && !uniqueNames[name])` to check if the cell is empty or not, so it will not included in count.

Answer (score -3):

Not going to get into formatting since you can probably figure that part out. You would use something like this and put it in a collection wherever you build billCollection you can add this to it, then you can reference that collection in your html

```
ClearCollect(colbillCount,ShowColumns( AddColumns( GroupBy(billcollection, "NumeralDenomination", "ByDenomination"), "DenominationCount", CountRows(ByDenomination) ), "NumeralDenomination", "DenominationCount" ))
```

**Please use these one in tobody and tr tag**

```
ForAll(colBillCount,colBillCount.NumberalDenomination

colBillCount.DenominationCount
```

thanks

Comment: To what Web API should `ClearCollect` and the other functions you mention belong to?

Comment: You _need_ to get into formatting. Your answer is very hard to read otherwise.